# How do I detect the connection protocol on the server with SignalR

Tags: signalr

How do I determine if a connection is using websockets, SSE, foreverframe, or long polling on the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine which transport method Signal R is using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551402/how-to-determine-which-transport-method-signal-r-is-using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the transport method by getting it from the querystring in your hub, like so:

```
string transport = Context.QueryString["transport"];
```